# How to control Control the legend SOM codes plot - plot.kohonen

Tags: r

I would like to access the legend on a kohonen SOM plot.  For example this code ...

```
library("kohonen")
data("wines")
wines.sc <- scale(wines)
set.seed(7)
wine.som <- som(wines.sc, grid = somgrid(5, 4, "hexagonal"))
plot(wine.som, main = "Wine data",shape="straight")
```

... creates a nice plot with a legend of the 13 variables in a 3 column 5 row format. How do I access the legend controls on this plot to make it say 2 columns by 7 rows or perhaps 4 columns with4 rows? Perhaps I need to somehow turn the legend off (not sure how) and create my own legend in the outer margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the `myplot.kohcodes` function [here](https://pastebin.com/fqKzgHd9) and save it in your working directory as `myplot.kohcodes.r`.
Set the number of columns in the legend using the `ncolsleg` parameter.
Then, run the code:

```
library("kohonen")
data("wines")
wines.sc <- scale(wines)
set.seed(7)
wine.som <- som(wines.sc, grid = somgrid(5, 4, "hexagonal"))

source("myplot.kohcodes.r")
myplot.kohcodes(wine.som, main = "Wine data", keepMargins=FALSE,
  palette.name=NULL, whatmap = NULL, codeRendering = NULL,
  bgcol = NULL, ncolsleg=2)
```

[image]

A note. If the legend width is greater than the plot width, `myplot.kohcodes` reduces the `cex` parameter until the legend width is lower that the plot width.

```
myplot.kohcodes <- function (x, whatmap, main, palette.name, bgcol, codeRendering,
    keepMargins, shape = c("round", "straight"), border = "black", ncolsleg=3,
    ...)
{
    if (!keepMargins) {
        opar <- par(c("mar"))
        on.exit(par(opar))
    }
    if (is.null(palette.name))
        palette.name <- terrain.colors
    whatmap <- check.whatmap(x, whatmap)
    nmaps <- length(whatmap)
    if (is.list(x$codes)) {
        for (i in 1:nmaps) {
            huhn <- list(whatmap = 1, grid = x$grid)
            huhn$codes <- getCodes(x, whatmap[i])
            if (length(main) == length(x$codes)) {
                main.title <- main[whatmap[i]]
            }
            else {
                if (length(main) == nmaps) {
                  main.title <- main[i]
                }
                else {
                  if (length(main) == 1) {
                    main.title <- main
                  }
                  else {
                    if (is.null(main)) {
                      if (!is.null(names(x$codes))) {
                        main.title <- names(x$codes)[whatmap[i]]
                      }
                      else {
                        main.title <- "Codes plot"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
            if (length(codeRendering) == length(x$codes)) {
                cR <- codeRendering[whatmap[i]]
            }
            else {
                if (length(codeRendering) == nmaps) {
                  cR <- codeRendering[i]
                }
                else {
                  cR <- codeRendering
                }
            }          
            myplot.kohcodes(huhn, main = main.title, palette.name = palette.name,
                bgcol = bgcol, whatmap = NULL, codeRendering = cR,
                keepMargins = TRUE, shape = shape, border = border, ncolsleg,
                ...)
        }
    }
    else {
        codes <- x$codes
        nvars <- ncol(codes)
        maxlegendcols <- 3
        ncols <- ncolsleg          
        print(ncolsleg)
        if (is.null(codeRendering))
            codeRendering <- ifelse(nvars < 15, "segments", "lines")
        margins <- rep(0.6, 4)
        if (!is.null(main))
            margins[3] <- margins[3] + 2
        par(mar = margins)
        if (codeRendering == "segments" & !is.null(colnames(codes))) {
            kohonen:::plot.somgrid(x$grid, ylim = c(max(x$grid$pts[, 2]) + min(x$grid$pts[,
                2]), -2))
            current.plot <- par("mfg")
            plot.width <- diff(par("usr")[1:2])
            cex <- 1

            leg.result <- legend(x = mean(x$grid$pts[, 1]), xjust = 0.5,
                y = 0, yjust = 1, legend = colnames(codes), cex = cex,
                plot = FALSE, ncol = ncols, fill = palette.name(nvars))
            while (leg.result$rect$w > plot.width) {
                cex <- cex * 0.9
                leg.result <- legend(x = mean(x$grid$pts[, 1]),
                  xjust = 0.5, y = 0, yjust = 1, legend = colnames(codes),
                  cex = cex, plot = FALSE, ncol = ncols, fill = palette.name(nvars))
            }
            leg.result <- legend(x = mean(x$grid$pts[, 1]), xjust = 0.5,
                y = 0, yjust = 1, cex = cex, legend = colnames(codes),
                plot = FALSE, ncol = ncols, fill = palette.name(nvars),
                ...)
            par(mfg = current.plot)
            kohonen:::plot.somgrid(x$grid, ylim = c(max(x$grid$pts[, 2]) + min(x$grid$pts[,
                2]), -leg.result$rect$h))
            legend(x = mean(x$grid$pts[, 1]), xjust = 0.5, y = 0,
                yjust = 1, cex = cex, plot = TRUE, legend = colnames(codes),
                ncol = ncols, fill = palette.name(nvars), ...)
        }
        else {
            plot(x$grid, ...)
        }
        title.y <- max(x$grid$pts[, 2]) + 1.2
        if (title.y > par("usr")[4] - 0.2) {
            title(main)
        }
        else {
            text(mean(range(x$grid$pts[, 1])), title.y, main,
                adj = 0.5, cex = par("cex.main"), font = par("font.main"))
        }
        if (is.null(bgcol))
            bgcol <- "transparent"
        shape <- match.arg(shape)
        sym <- ifelse(shape == "round", "circle", ifelse(x$grid$topo ==
            "rectangular", "square", "hexagon"))
        switch(sym, circle = symbols(x$grid$pts[, 1], x$grid$pts[,
            2], circles = rep(0.5, nrow(x$grid$pts)), inches = FALSE,
            add = TRUE, fg = border, bg = bgcol), hexagon = hexagons(x$grid$pts[,
            1], x$grid$pts[, 2], unitcell = 1, col = bgcol, border = border),
            square = symbols(x$grid$pts[, 1], x$grid$pts[, 2],
                squares = rep(1, nrow(x$grid$pts)), inches = FALSE,
                add = TRUE, fg = border, bg = bgcol))
        if (codeRendering == "lines") {
            yrange <- range(codes)
            codes <- codes - mean(yrange)
        }
        else {
            codemins <- apply(codes, 2, min)
            codes <- sweep(codes, 2, codemins)
        }
        switch(codeRendering, segments = {
            stars(codes, locations = x$grid$pts, labels = NULL,
                len = 0.4, add = TRUE, col.segments = palette.name(nvars),
                draw.segments = TRUE)
        }, lines = {
            for (i in 1:nrow(x$grid$pts)) {
                if (yrange[1] < 0 & yrange[2] > 0) {
                  lines(seq(x$grid$pts[i, 1] - 0.4, x$grid$pts[i,
                    1] + 0.4, length = 2), rep(x$grid$pts[i,
                    2], 2), col = "gray")
                }
                lines(seq(x$grid$pts[i, 1] - 0.4, x$grid$pts[i,
                  1] + 0.4, length = ncol(codes)), x$grid$pts[i,
                  2] + codes[i, ] * 0.8/diff(yrange), col = "red")
            }
        }, stars = stars(codes, locations = x$grid$pts, labels = NULL,
            len = 0.4, add = TRUE))
    }
    invisible()
}
```

Comment: Marco - this was much more complicated than anticipated and I having trouble with adapting it to more general situations as I'm getting error  'could not fin function "hexagons" and not sure why.  Thanks very much for your efforts but it seems best to just accept the default legend from Kohonen.map for this minor cosmetic adjustment I was seeking.

Comment: Can you please upload the code for the function? (for those who can't download files on company computer)

Comment: @PeyM87 OK. Done.